# Change attribute ArrayList<Class> to ArrayList<SubClass> in a subclass

Tags: java, arraylist

Well hello, here is my problem.

I would like to know if, given an `abstract class Foo`, it is possible to, somehow, get its attribute `ArrayList<Bar>` (Bar being abstract too) to only contain a certain specific subclass of what it used to contain in every subclass of `Foo`.

For example, in a concrete `class FooChild` that `extends Foo`, the attribute `ArrayList<Bar>` would now only contain concrete `class BarChild` (which `extends Bar`).

More specifically, if I got this piece of code:

```
public abstract class CharactersGroup {
    private ArrayList<Character> characters;

    public CharactersGroup() {
        this(new ArrayList<Character>());
    }

    public CharactersGroup(ArrayList<Character> list) {
        characters = list;
    }
}
```

And a subclass of `CharactersGroup` would be `HeroesGroup`, like this:

```
public class HeroesGroup extends CharactersGroup {
    // Here is an ArrayList<Character> characters, that I would like to "become" an ArrayList<Hero> characters

    public HeroesGroup() {
        this(new ArrayList<Hero>());
    }

    public HeroesGroup(ArrayList<Hero> list) {
        super(list);
    }
}
```

A `Character` would be just like:

```
public abstract class Character {
    private String name;

    public Character(String n) {
        name = n;;
    }
}
```

And a `Hero` like:

```
public class Hero extends Character {
    private int level;

    public Hero(String n, int l) {
        super(n);
        level = l;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your abstract class `CharactersGroup` generic.

```
public abstract class CharactersGroup<C extends Character> {
    private ArrayList<C> characters;

    public CharactersGroup() {
        this(new ArrayList<C>());
    }

    public CharactersGroup(ArrayList<C> list) {
        characters = list;
    }
}
```

Subclasses look like this:

```
public class HeroesGroup extends CharactersGroup<Hero> {

    public HeroesGroup() {
        this(new ArrayList<Hero>());
    }

    public HeroesGroup(ArrayList<Hero> list) {
        super(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a generic parameter on the superclass:

```
public abstract class CharactersGroup<C extends Character> {
    private ArrayList<C extends Character> characters;

    public CharactersGroup() {
        this(new ArrayList<C extends Character>());
    }

    public CharactersGroup(ArrayList<C extends Character> list) {
        characters = list;
    }
}

public class HeroesGroup extends CharactersGroup<Hero> {
    // Here is an ArrayList<Character> characters, that I would like to "become" an ArrayList<Hero> characters

    public HeroesGroup() {
        this(new ArrayList<Hero>());
    }

    public HeroesGroup(ArrayList<Hero> list) {
        super(list);
    }
}
```